# No vertical space between question title and question

Tags: exsheets

In a book I am writing I want to write various exercises for problems. For this purpose I am using the package exsheets. How can I ensure that the text for the question is immediately after the heading Exercise 1 and not below it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
 What is $1+1$?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Second question:
I am having ver 0.17 of this package and miktex is not showing it in the updatable list. The exsheets site is showing version 0.18. How do I update it?

Comment: `\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}`? Please read section 20 *Styling your Exercise/Exam Sheets* of `exsheets`' manual

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the following option:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runin} % chapter 20.2 on page 40-41 of `texdoc exsheets`
    \begin{question}
        What is $1+1$?
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Regarding the update: I believe, you have to wait. I am having 0.17, too. You could write the [maintainer](http://miktex.org/contact) of MiKTeX in order to get the update the normal way. Or you download the new version from [its source](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets).